# Keeping track of pending records to be posted in a Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to keep track of how many records are left to be processed when adding a bunch of records to a room database.  I have tried the following code, but at the end, "pendingRecords" shows a positive value instead of zero:

```
  viewModelScope.launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      pendingRecords++
      database?.pressureDao()?.insert(sensorData)}
  }.invokeOnCompletion { pendingRecords-- }
```

My DAO looks like this:

```
  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  fun insert(sensor: Pressure)
```

Not sure if it makes any difference that this is nested within another

```
  viewModelScope.launch {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
```

What am I missing here?  Is there a better solution to this?

Oliver

Comment: Have you tried adding the `pendingRecords--` after the `withContext()` call?

Comment: I tried it.  pendingRecords is still non-zero.  Before it was positive, now it is negative.  Interestingly the final value is never the same even though I am testing with the same dataset.  Could ++/-- be non-reentrant and stepping on each other!?